# Facebook Connect: hasPermission() from js?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to determine whether a user has granted my app a specific permission or not via javascript?

Something similar to how you do it in php:

```
$fb->api_client->users_hasAppPermission('publish_stream');
```

I know i can request a permission with

```
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog('publish_stream', null);
```

But i just wan't to know if i have the permission or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it:

```
FB.Facebook.apiClient.users_hasAppPermission("publish_stream",function(res){alert(res)});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those coming in from Google, this can be done using the Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=...
```